# Django unable to find post variable

Tags: django, http

I have following test code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def view_test(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if 'Var1' in request.POST :
            return HttpResponse("Flip")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Flop")
```

I wanted to pass data to my django server via a GPRS and I am sending this "HTTP Packet"

```
    POST /test_pkt/ HTTP/1.1 \r\n
    Host: test.my_django_server.com \r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 \r\n
    Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html \r\n
    Accept-Encoding: deflate \r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US \r\n
    Connection: keep-alive \r\n
    Referer: http://test.my_django_server.com/test_pkt/ \r\n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n
    Content-Length: 11 \r\n
    Var1=toggle\r\n
    \r\n
```

and In response I get

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2012 13:11:23 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Server: gunicorn/0.14.6

    c
    flop
    0
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but I couldn't find out. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can put an assertion after `if request.method=="POST":`. Something like `assert 0, request.POST`. So you can see what you get

Comment: POST data goes in the body of the request. You probably need an extra blank line between the last header (content-length) and the data.

Comment: try `dict = request.post.copy(); dict.get('Var1', None)` if you look into dict, you should have `Var1`

Comment: @DanielRoseman is correct. You are sending Var1 as a header, not as POST data. So Var1 will be in request.META

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, POST data goes in the body of a request. The body is always separated from the headers by a blank line, so you need a blank line between the last header (`Content-Length`) and the body.